# Can I Combine Two Lights from Separate Breakers Into One Switch?

Tags: switch, light

I have two outdoor lights that are separate switches.  I want to combine them under one switch, but Light A is on Breaker #3 and Light B is on Breaker #2.  Can I put these lights on the same switch or do I have to keep them separate since they are on different Breakers?  If I can combine them, what type of switch do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. You will need a double pole single throw switch. They are commonly available at your home stores.....  be careful not to get a 4-way switch... they look almost identical. [image]

Comment: However, now the 2 breakers must be handle-tied. 2 circuits, 1 yoke.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Good catch!